# Error installing Log.io on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, logging, installation, npm

When I try to install log io for the first time I get this error, using npm:

**sudo npm install -g log.io --user "ubuntu"**

```
Error: setuid user id does not exist
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:49:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

Comment: There's no user with name "ubuntu" in you mac (since you have osx tag). Try your name or create another user account and give its name here.